# Can I paint the electrical panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, paint

I am painting the room in our basement that contains the electrical panel. I think it would look a lot better to paint the panel the same color as the wall, instead of the plain grey-green metal. I've heard that it's against code (USA) to paint the electrical panels, but I wasn't sure why. It's my own house and we don't rent it out, so I'm not too worried about the code violation.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't paint the electrical panel, and are there any problems I should watch for when painting it? The panel is brand new with no rust, so I will likely need to roughen the surface with sandpaper first.

Comment: Not worrying about code violations "because you own it" is a very bad plan. You WILL get caught, you WILL have to fix it, and it'll happen at sale time, when you are rushing to close a sale, which means you won't have the leisure to DIY and will probably have to hire it done.

Comment: This panel is flushmounted into the wall, correct?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I guess I just meant that if I understood the code (if there were one) and what hazards it was trying to prevent, then I could possibly try to follow the spirit if not the letter of the rule, or knowledgeably accept the given risk for myself. But, I take your point.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, it's flushmounted, and I believe the linked question is the same as mine. However, Harper's answer there has a few too many acronyms for me to understand.

Comment: @DavidK Typically there are *multiple* reasons for a rule. One must be careful not to grab the first (or most convenient) one, rationalize it away, and then be unaware of the other reasons or the knock-on effects then created when other rules were expecting this one to be followed.  Neutrals and grounds being at the top of the hitlist.

Answer (score 3):

What you "heard" is incorrect, but Harper's advice is wise just the same.

You *can* paint the outer cover of the panel as long as you don't obscure any critical labels. Use a good primer and several thin topcoats to prevent runs and avoid filling stamped text. I'd probably remove the plastic latch, mask the opening from behind, and reinstall it later for a more professional appearance (or simply mask it in place).